# How to get the timestamp date from firebase firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

How to get the correct timestamp in iOS from Firebase firestore?

[image]

I have field called as  `playerLoginTime: November 30, 2018 at 4:12:20 PM UTC+5:30`

But when I try to  get I am getting wrong results.

> 2018-11-30 10:47:12 +0000

I want to get date in the form of `MMM dd,yyyy`.

My Queries below:

```
let docRef = db.collection("employees").document(userID)
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        if document.get("playerLoginTime") != nil {
            self.loginTime = document.get("playerLoginTime") as! Date;
            print("Before printdates  \(self.loginTime )")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `November 30, 2018 at 4:12:20 PM UTC+5:30` and `2018-11-30 10:47:12 +0000` are the same. It represents the same date, no? You notice the "UTC+5:30" and the "+0000" which is why you have 5h:30 difference? If you want to print it as such "November 30, 2018 at 4:12:20 PM UTC+5:30", you'll need a `DateFormatter()`, but that's just a representation of the seconds from unixTimeStamp.

Comment: @Larme ok sir...But I android what is there in database same thing returning.i iOS it give me result 5.30 hr different..

Comment: @Larme I want to get date in the form of `MMM dd,yyyy` please help me how can I get it

Comment: Because it's interpreting the date? A `(NS)Date` as said is just an object that encapsulate the number of seconds from 1st January 70 (to simplify). What if you are in UK or in India? Wouldn't you to get the date according to your TimeZone? Then you use a `(NS)DateFormatter`. Look at all the question to go from `Date` to `String` using a `DateFormatter`. It's a common question, you have plenty of points in SO, you should be able to find the answer, now that you get the key words to search for.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your suggestion sir....actually I do not have knowadge  in iOS and swift...I will try how can I achieve...

Answer (score 1):

I think I had this issue as well.

I fixed it by casting to `TimeStamp` which is a Firebase type instead of `Date` and then converting to `Date` with `dateFormatter` before displaying.

To get the `TimeStamp` type, you just import Firebase into the file you need it in.

**Bonus Tip**: Instead of converting it yourself (and if you don't mind open source libraries), I'd suggest using the [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) library! It's extremely easy to use and conversion from `TimeStamp` to `Date` to a formatted date was easy. Moreover, you can also easily convert to Twitter-like timestamps (i.e. `2m` for 2 minutes ago)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

```
    let docRef = db.collection("employees").document(userID)
     docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {

            if document.get("playerLoginTime") != nil {
                    self.loginTime = document.get("playerLoginTime") as! Date;
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
                    self.loginTime = dateFormatter.string(from: self.loginTime)

                }

}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Good answers explain what was wrong and explain how the answer solves the problem.

Comment: @Haani Dev `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Date'` I getting this error........In this line  **dateFormatter.string(from: self.loginTime)**